# Design the digital IIR filter with the following specifications

Tags: infinite-impulse-response

Lower stopband edge = 25 Hz
Lower passband edge = 100 Hz
Upper stopband edge = 225 Hz
Upper passband edge = 150 Hz
Stopband attenuation = 18 dB
Passband ripple = 3 dB
Sampling frequency = 500 Hz.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to design a digital IIR filter with the parameters (specifications);


Lower stopband edge = 25 dB, Lower passband edge = 100 Hz, Upper stopband edge = 225, dB Upper passband edge = 150 Hz, Stopband attenuation = 18 dB, Passband ripple = 3 dB, Sampling frequency = 500 Hz. I don't know how to.

Comment: Hello Sakthidhar, and welcome! Is this a question about theory or practice? If it is the former, you’d need to show us what you have tried and where you’re having trouble. No one is going to teach you filter design from scratch here. If it is the latter, do you have access to any software package such as Matlab? In general, this website isn’t a place where you’ll get answers to such a custom request, but you’ll get guidance and help as you work out the process yourself.

Comment: `Upper stopband edge = 225 dB` Are you sure? That sounds really, really wrong.